# table in ms sql with primary key and auto_increment problem

Tags: sql, increment

hi i found an answer here and used the exemple

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    Personid int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int
);
```

but when i enter records, it does not allow duplicates in column lastname?!

[image: table persons]

i would expect id 3 and "hans" but it makes NULL?! it shouldnt be a problem that there is again name hans in row 3 ...

what do i wrong?

[image]

Comment: Which version of `SQL Server Management Studio` are you using?  I cannot reproduce this using version v18.11.1

Comment: its version 18.10

Comment: Sorry, I can reproduce the problem..... but I do not understand why this happens

Comment: I happens when you enter `hans`, leave the row, and then go back to the new row. Normally the `Personid` should be determined when you leave the row.....

Comment: @Luuk. please see my second image in my post. it skips and adds further records but line 3 hans id is empty

Comment: i closed the table and reopened it and now there is id 3 for hans in line 3. crazy (Y)

Comment: As a work around you can press `CTRL+R`, which refreshes the data, but this look like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If do you want to do autoincrement on Personid, you should do:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
Personid int AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Age int,
PRIMARY KEY (Personid) );
```

And if do you want insert something into:

```
INSERT INTO Persons (LastName, FirstName, Age int) VALUES (..,..,..)
```

I hope I've helped.

Comment: Meldung 102, Ebene 15, Status 1, Zeile 2
Falsche Syntax in der Nähe von "AUTO_INCREMENT".

Comment: In Xampp  it's okey, have you copied right? I tried on my computer and it works

Comment: i use ms sql not mysql

Comment: "CREATE TABLE (
  ID_column INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY...  " and this?

Comment: thank you! it works with my create command in my opening post above. the "problem" was, that it looks like so until i close the table. when i reopen it, its the correct id :-)

Comment: str+r / ctrl+r correct, thank you! refreshes the reocrds and shows me the ids (Y)